# navigation bar with no line breaks and a resizing breadcrumb on the left and fixed menu on right

Tags: html, css, navigationbar, breadcrumbs

I am trying to find a solution to automatically resize a breadcrumb within a navigation bar using just css and no js.

The navigation bar should be 100% width.
On the right a user menu should always be shown.
On the left is the breadcrumb navigation. Elements within that element should resize `using text-overflow: ellipsis`

I have tried various things so far. I can't float the user menu to the right as this would push it to the bottom whenever I run out of space. However the navigation bar just should be one line.

I then tried to make use of a table layout, to keep the navigation bar just one line, with the user menu and the breadcrumb each being one table-cell. However, the user menu just gets pushed to the right outside of the screen whenever there is not enough space instead of shortening the breadcrumbs.

here is how the navigation bar should behave:

in case there is sufficient space, the breadcrumb sticks to the left and the user menu to the right

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bread 1 > bread 2                                        user logout |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In case there is not enough space, the user menu should stay on the right with its full size. Whereas the breadcrumb should get shortened.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| very very long br.... > very very long br.... > very..   user logout |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the basic markup:

```
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><div>one &gt;</div></li>
    <li><div>two is longer than one &gt;</div></li>
    <li><div>three is longer than two</div></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="user">
    <div>dont</div>
    <div>resize</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and here is the corresponding fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eex8yrLt/

Comment: Question: why did you put a div around each word inside div.user?

Comment: because they are separate elements, which the user menu consists of. For instance one div might be the notifications and the second div might be the actual account related stuff.

Comment: you need text-overflow i guess now :)

Comment: can you move the div.user before the ol?  If so, I think I have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using flexbox seemed to be the only way to meet all my requirements.

given the markup

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="bread">
        <span>
            1 breadcrumb
        </span>
        <span>
            2 very long breadcrumb
        </span>
        <span>
            3 very long breadcrumb
        </span>

    </div>
    <div class="user">
        <span>
            hello
        </span>
        <span>
            user
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

first of the navigation bar itself needs to be a flexbox

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

then the breadcrumb container needs to be another flexbox so it scales each item down equally and a nowrap for the white-space so everything stays within a single line.

```
.bread {
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

each item of the breadcrumb overflows using ellipsis

```
.bread span {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and lastly, the user menu should not flex at all and gets a `margin-left: auto` so it will stick to the right side.

```
.user {
    flex: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/7oyu34gg/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you can move the div.user before the <ol> here is a solution for you.  It's based on making the list items have display: inline;

```css
nav {
  width: 70%;
}
nav * {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
.user {
  float: right;
  background: lightcoral;
}
.name, .acct-no {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="user">
    <span class="name">John Doe</span>
    <span class="acct-no">1267902</span>
  </div>
  <ol>
    <li>one &gt;</li>
    <li>two is longer than one &gt;</li>
    <li>three is longer than two</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's very close to what I am looking for. Your answer inspired me to try a few other things and I think I found a solution using flexbox, which resizes all breadcrumb elements instead of just the last one: https://jsfiddle.net/7oyu34gg/